# Call cron.php once a day - Magento settings

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.8

Like a lot of users i've some problems configuring Magento cronjobs (my cartrules doesn't update properly on Magento 1.8.1. I also modified my cron.php adding $isShellDisabled = true;).

A tried a lot of things, but it doesn't work. Installed AOE scheduler, and i see all my tasks as pending!

My hosting let me to call cron.php once a day (3 am, and it's working, becase it generates the tasks at that time), so i'm wondering if is useless having settings like this:

```
Generate Schedules Every 15

Schedule Ahead for 1

Missed if Not Run Within 60

History Cleanup Every 120

Success History Lifetime 1400

Failure History Lifetime 1400
```

If i run manually the `cron.php`, it generates tasks for a hour, all pending (for example, my cart rules XML are set to update every 15 minutes, so i get 4 cartrules tasks)

If i run it again (after few minutes), all tasks between this time change form Pending to Success.

So, have i to call it at least twice a day? Or i have to change my cron settings?

thank you for the help

Comment: Once a day?  Get a new host, it should be run every 5 minutes -> */5 * * * *

Comment: Maybe you can consider creating a wrapper script that runs forever and has a sleep of 300 seconds between each call to cron.php. It will very likely lead to all sort of issues if it doesn't run every 5-10 minutes.

Comment: It's on a shared server, so crontabs are limited. Once a hour would be ok?

Comment: A host that limits your cron jobs to once a day isn't a web host that can properly service Magento. You have major issues cropping up in your future. For proper running of the nightly multiple jobs that are expected to run, you need once every 15 minutes from about 11pm to 6am.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. magento.stackexchange is a more appropriate venue for asking about Magento admin questions and light duty server setups.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cron expression for each hour:

```
<cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

This will make it run at `12.00`, `1.00` and so on.
If you want to make it run at `12.30`, `1.30` and so on replace `0` with `30`

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't it work with a cron expression of a quarter of hour, too (like mine) ? It also runs on the hour...